# how to get string from array in cakephp?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, pdo, cakephp-bake

I want to insert data in cakephp from add from. I got array in `$this->request->data['ProductValue']` 
at controller. My array is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => Deepak1
        [value] => Option1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Deepak2
        [value] => Ans1, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Deepak3
        [value] => Product1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => Deepak4
        [value] => Radio1
    )

)
```

but i need this type of array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => Deepak1
        [value] => Option1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Deepak2
        [value] => Array
            (
                [0] => Ans1
                [1] => Ans2
                [2] => Ans3
                [3] => Ans4
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Deepak3
        [value] => Product1
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => Deepak4
        [value] => Radio1
    )

)
```

please tell me how to do this...

Comment: just explode it on `,`

Answer (score 0):

```
function prepare(&$List) {
 foreach($List as &$element) {
  $tmp = explode(', ', $element['value']);
  if(count($tmp) <= 1) { continue; }
  $element['value'] = $tmp;
 }
}

prepare($YourArray);
```